# Can I get real time Firebase DB total storage size?

Tags: firebase

With Firebase, is there any way to get the storage metrics (how much data is being stored in the DB) in real time?

The analytics tab in the firebase dashboard has a 1 hour delay and sometimes I don't think the "Storage" value updates at all.

I'm trying to optimize client side string compression and see its impact on DB size.  The delay makes this testing difficult and time consuming.

Any ideas?

Comment: In a language like Python, you could get the firebase through `requests` or the firebase library for Python and then check the filesize

Comment: How big are the strings you are storing?? You may also want to check out Firebase Storage and have the string in a text file (or the native file format if it's not text).

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38762731/get-storage-space-used-in-a-folder-in-firebase-storage), with an answer by a member of the Firebase team... for anyone searching for similar topics in the future. Doesn't actually provide example code, but he makes a suggestion.