# Get storage space used in a folder in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I'm creating a Firebase app that you can use to upload files. How can I get the amount of space used by a user in his folder `(users/{userId}/{allPaths=**})` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question. In short, there's no easy way to do this (even for us!) since this effectively requires that we recurse over an entire set of files and sum them all up. It's a pretty big mapreduce that isn't efficient to run every time a file is uploaded.

We do however, return the size of an individual file in the `metadata.size` property, so you can perform your own `list` call on a server (look at [gcloud](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-common)`) which will give you a list of files and "folders". Take the sizes of the files and add them up, then recurse and do the same for all subfolders. Sum them up, and write them something like the Firebase Realtime Database, where you can easily grab the folder sizes from clients.

Comment: If you know the total usage of the storage, it means you have, already, a procedure that sums those values. The point would be to segregate them, based on different criteria

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little script I wrote that calculates the count of files and bytes used for each of your "folders" and outputs to console.

```
function main(bucketName = 'YOUR_BUCKET_NAME') {
  /**
   * TODO(developer): Uncomment the following line before running the sample.
   */
  // const bucketName = 'Name of a bucket, e.g. my-bucket';

  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();

  async function listFiles() {
    // Lists files in the bucket
    const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

    console.log('Files:');
    let bucketList = {};
    files.forEach(file => {
      let folder = file.name.split('/')[0];
      if (!bucketList[folder]) {
        bucketList[folder] = {};
        bucketList[folder]['bytes'] = 0;
        bucketList[folder]['count'] = 0;
      }
      bucketList[folder]['bytes'] += Number(file.metadata.size);
      bucketList[folder]['count'] +=1;

    });
    console.log(bucketList);
  }

  listFiles().catch(console.error);
  // [END storage_list_files]
}
main(...process.argv.slice(2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getFolderSize: async function (folderPath) {
    try {
        this.size = 0;
        this.storage = firebase.storage();
        await this.getFolderSizeRecursive(folderPath);
        return this.size;
    } catch (err) {
        // probably denied permissions or 'path/to/storage/folder' is not a folder
        console.error(err)
    }

},

getFolderSizeRecursive: async function (folderPath) {
    const ref = this.storage.ref(folderPath);
    const list = await ref.listAll();

    for (const fileRef of list.items) {
        await this.addSizeItem(fileRef.fullPath);

    }
    for (const folderRef of list.prefixes) {
        await this.getFolderSizeRecursive(folderRef.fullPath);
    }
},

// Usage
addSizeItem: async function (filePath) {
    const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);
    let metaData = await fileRef.getMetadata()
    this.size = this.size + metaData.size;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly improved version based on @Mike's answer that also outputs size recursively for all subfolders and prints size in "human readable" format, ie MB, kB etc.

It also writes output to a json file that you can explore using some json viewers like https://jsoneditoronline.org/.

Note that you also need to pass a serviceaccount.json as credentials to Storage

```
function main(bucketName) {


    // Imports the Google Cloud client library
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const fs = require('fs').promises;
// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage({
    credentials: //your service account json key
});



async function listFiles() {
    // Lists files in the bucket
    const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucketName).getFiles();

    console.log('Files:');
    let bucketList = {};
    files.forEach(file => {
        let folders = file.name.split('/');
        let curFolder = bucketList
        folders.forEach(subFolder => {
            if (!curFolder[subFolder]) {
                curFolder[subFolder] = {};
                curFolder[subFolder]['bytes'] = 0;
                curFolder[subFolder]['count'] = 0;
            }
            curFolder[subFolder]['bytes'] += Number(file.metadata.size);
            curFolder[subFolder]['count'] +=1;
            curFolder[subFolder]['size'] = humanFileSize(curFolder[subFolder]['bytes'])
            curFolder = curFolder[subFolder]
        })

    });
    console.log(bucketList);
    await fs.writeFile("sizes.json", JSON.stringify(bucketList))
}

function humanFileSize(bytes, si=true, dp=1) {
    const thresh = si ? 1000 : 1024;

    if (Math.abs(bytes) < thresh) {
        return bytes + ' B';
    }

    const units = si
        ? ['kB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB']
        : ['KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB', 'ZiB', 'YiB'];
    let u = -1;
    const r = 10**dp;

    do {
        bytes /= thresh;
        ++u;
    } while (Math.round(Math.abs(bytes) * r) / r >= thresh && u < units.length - 1);


    return bytes.toFixed(dp) + ' ' + units[u];
}

listFiles().catch(console.error);
// [END storage_list_files]
}

//TODO change the name of the bucket to yours

main("my-bucket-name");
```